# How do I prevent Android taking a screenshot when my app goes to the background? and then place my own custom view

Tags: android, android-view

I know this will do the trick of securing the activity

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

I need to place my own custom view instead of the blank default view.

- Regarding this duplicate, `onCreateThumbnail` is not getting called. and the ref provided is not actually working for me

Comment: The answer to this question's duplicate is correct according to Android's documentation, but there is a years old bug (still open after 5 years) that prevents this from working correctly. Unfortunately, there is no really acceptable workaround. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36945159